# Error "syntax error near unexpected token '('" in Bash script when selecting files

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Running this script, `bash ./cleanup.bash`,

```
#!/bin/bash
## Going to directory-moving stuff
rm -rf !(composer.json|.git)
```

Gives the error:

> cleanup.bash: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token '('
> cleanup.bash: line 10: 'rm -rf !(composer.json|.git)'

But if I run in in the terminal directly, there aren't any problems:

```
rm -rf !(composer.json|.git)
```

I tried stripping out all other lines, but I still get the error.

How do I enter this correctly in the Bash script?

I'm on Ubuntu, and this was all done locally, not on a remote.

Comment: check previous lines also

Comment: nope, even when it's the only line in the file. it gives this error.

Comment: try doing `set -o posix` or `set +o posix` before `rm` command.

Comment: `posix` also doesn't help :/ (again the only two lines)

Comment: @Inian I'm on ubuntu myself. And typed this script as I tried them in the terminal. Also doing all this locally, not on a remote. the `cat` didn't show anything different.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html have you tried removing !?

Comment: @IriaPoncelaBlanco removeing the `!` doesn't help. Scimming the guide, didn't find anything

Comment: @Inian that gives a new error `line 9: set: -s: invalid option`

Comment: @janw: I meant it to be `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: A now-deleted "answer" said: *"I tried to run the command in my home directory, "rm -rf !(composer.json|.git)", and all my data got deleted."*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess your problem is due to the shell extended glob option not set when run from the script. When you claim it works in the command line, you have somehow set the `extglob` flag which allow to `!()` globs.

Since the Bash script, whenever started with a `#!/bin/bash`, starts a new sub-shell, the extended options set in the parent shell may not be reflected in the new shell. To make it take effect, set it in the script after the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

## Going to directory-moving stuff
rm -rf !(composer.json|.git)
```

Comment: yep this is it :)

Comment: Important to run this outside of any "scope" of the script (ex. for loop, if block, etc).  If you run shopt -s extglob only inside an 'if' block, it won't be in effect there.  Running it after the she-bang as this answer states avoids the problem.