# syntax error near unexpected token '(' in bash script when selecting files [extend]

Tags: bash, makefile

Question similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304329/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-in-bash-script-when-selecting-files), but for my use case, I'd like to place inside the makefile.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Example: 
#   make run TEST_CASE="testbench.sv"
#   make clean

compile:
    vcs $(TEST_CASE) -sverilog;

run: compile
    ./simv

uvm_compile:
    vcs $(TEST_CASE) -sverilog;

clean:
    shopt -s extglob;
    rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");
```

The problem exist in make clean, and I got the following result:

```
ycliao@localhost:[~/workspace/i2c_vip/uvm_practice]: make clean
shopt -s extglob;
rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Comment: Add a line continuation (a backslash) to the first line of the recipe. Make sure it is the last character of the line. As the recipe is written the two lines are executed in two different shells and the `extglob` option is set only for the first shell. Other possibilities: use the `.ONESHELL` GNU make feature or write the recipe on a single line. Note: except for this first line of the `clean` recipe, all other semi-colons are useless.

Comment: As you mentioned the "backslash" to be added, I do not get the point. Can you show me how to modify the current code? Huge thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the backslash character is? It looks like this: \. Just add one at the end of the line `shopt -s extglob;`.

Comment: Even with this, it will not work as-is.  At least, not portably.  That behavior is not available in a POSIX shell, it will only work in bash.  But make doesn't invoke bash by default, it invokes `/bin/sh`.  On some systems `/bin/sh` is actually bash and it will work.  On other systems, `/bin/sh` is a simple POSIX shell and it will fail.  If you want make to always use `bash` you have to set the variable `SHELL = /bin/bash`.

Comment: @MadScientist Good point. I forgot to add that the shown shebang does not work in a Makefile.

Comment: Well, it _works_ in that if you try to run the makefile as a program it will invoke bash... which will then promptly fail because this is a makefile not a shell script :).  But, yeah, it means nothing whatever to make.  Just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so for in the makefile is not available to have ```  shopt -s extglob ``` ?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand makefiles, every line is executed in a separate shell. So you need to add a line continuation to concatenate the commands so that they execute in the *same* shell:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

# ...

clean:
    shopt -s extglob; \
    rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");
```

This is demonstrated in [Example makefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Example_makefiles) on the wikipedia Make page.

Comment: This is also the way I tried, but do not work for me

Comment: ycliao@localhost:[~/workspace/i2c_vip/uvm_practice]: make clean
shopt -s extglob; \
rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");'
make: *** [clean] Error 1

Comment: Seems still does not work. I give a sum up for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is a bash problem. For some reason, it doesn't seem possible to do shopt followed by some command as a one-liner. Let's take make completely out of the picture. In a bash shell:

```
$ ls -1 /tmp/hosts.tar.*
/tmp/hosts.tar.bz2
/tmp/hosts.tar.gz
$ shopt -s extglob ; ls -1 /tmp/hosts.tar.@(bz2|gz)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ ls -1 /tmp/hosts.tar.@(bz2|gz)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls -1 /tmp/hosts.tar.@(bz2|gz)
/tmp/hosts.tar.bz2
/tmp/hosts.tar.gz
```

Answer (score -2):

To Sum up, for the makefile, it is not allow to have this.

```
ycliao@localhost:[~/workspace/i2c_vip/uvm_practice]: make clean
shopt -s extglob; \
rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `rm -v !(*.sv|*svh|"makefile");'
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Comment: @glenn jackman for the error message

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).